# Cocoa: create graphs

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, graphing, linegraph, bar-chart

Is there a framework out there that will allow me to create simple bar and line graphs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the newer, open source,  [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Answer (score 3):

There's the [GraphX](http://blog.oofn.net/projects/graphx/) framework - I played with it years ago; I don't know what status it's in these days.

**UPDATE**: there's also [SM2DGraphView](http://developer.snowmintcs.com/frameworks/sm2dgraphview/).